# Inserting a Centered Title in a Tikzpicture without Adversely Affecting Text Wrapping

Tags: tikz-pgf, titles, wrap, wrapfig

I am producing a somewhat syntactically complex tikzpicture, which thanks to the help of David Carlisle, looks like this:

[image]

The code which generates that picture is as follows.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

\newlength\zzz
\setlength\zzz{10pt}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\definecolor{pylight}{RGB}{247, 235, 205}
\definecolor{py}{RGB}{243, 224, 181}
\definecolor{pydark}{RGB}{221, 182, 110}
\definecolor{pyhighlight}{RGB}{254, 235, 204}

\pgfdeclareverticalshading{parchment}{100bp}{%
  color(0bp)=(pydark);
  color(25bp)=(pydark);
  color(30bp)=(py);
  color(50bp)=(pylight);
  color(70bp)=(py);
  color(75bp)=(pydark);
  color(100bp)=(pydark)%
}
\pgfdeclareradialshading{rparchment}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}{%
  color(0bp)=(pylight);
  color(13bp)=(pylight);
  color(20bp)=(py);
  color(40bp)=(pydark);
  color(60bp)=(pydark!50!black);
  color(100bp)=(black)%
}
\tikzset{
  pencildraw/.style={%
    decorate,  decoration={%
      random steps, segment length=1.1ex, amplitude=.5ex%
    }
  },
  drop shadow/.style={
    blur shadow={%
      shadow xshift=.5pt,
      shadow yshift=-.5pt,
      shadow blur steps=9,
      shadow blur extra rounding=1.5pt%
    },
  },
  parchment fill/.style={
    pencildraw, fill=pyhighlight,
    postaction={shading=parchment, opacity=1},
    postaction={shading=rparchment, opacity=.7}
  }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \shade node[preaction={fill=black,opacity=.5,transform canvas={xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm}},parchment fill, drop shadow,
    inner sep=5mm]
  {\parbox{0.87\textwidth}{\fontsize{13}{16}\selectfont
    \vspace{\zzz}%
    \hangindent=\dimexpr 0.2\textwidth+\columnsep\relax
    \hangafter=-3
    \noindent\llap{\raisebox{\dimexpr \zzz+0.6\baselineskip-\height}[0pt][0pt]% overlap indentation
      {\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}}\hspace{\columnsep}}%      
      %\textbf{\textcolor{red}{Objective: a Centered Title}} \vskip 8pt
    \textbf{\textit{\lipsum[2]}}}} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would now like to add a centered title directly above the paragraph and to the right of the image. However, when I add the line

```
\textbf{\textcolor{red}{Objective: a Centered Title}} \vskip 8pt (presently commented out in the above code), it produces
```

[image]

I have not been able to correct the undesirable positioning of the subsequent text, nor have I been able to center the title (save using an `\hskip`) which I do not want to do as I intend to use this box for a variety of purposes---and would like to automatically have the title centered. Also, `\centering`{the line of code} seems to center everything including each individual line of the paragraph.

QUESTION: Can anyone suggest how I may be able to center the title, as well as have the subsequent text of the paragraph wrap around the image in an appropriate way (as in the first tikzpicture)?

Thank you.